# How continuity of $f$ and path-connectedness of $g$ results in $f\circ g$ to be path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Theorem 6.29 (p.213) of *Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applied* by C Adams and R Franzosa says:

> Assume that $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and $X$ is path connected. Then $f (X)$ is a path connected subspace of $Y$.
>
> Proof. Let $p$ and $q$ be points in $f(X)$. Pick points $x \in {f}^{-1} ({\{p\}})$ and $y \in {f}^{-1} ({\{q\}})$. Since $X$ is path connected, there exists a path $g: [0, 1] \rightarrow X$ from $x$ to $y$. Then $f\circ g$ is a path in $f(X)$ from $p$ to $q$.

What I don't understand is the last sentence of the proof. How continuity of $f$ and path-connectedness of $g$ results in $f\circ g$ to be path-connected?

Comment: $g$ is not connected and $f\circ g$ is not path-connected. Those words describe spaces, not functions. Can you visualize what's going on here? Given two points of $Y$, pull them back to $X$, put a path between them, then push the path forward into $Y$. Draw a picture if you need to, visualization is important.

Comment: @anon I don't understand the last sentence of the proof (copy-pasted from the book), to complete the proof.

Comment: Since $f\circ g$ is a composition of continuous functions, it is continuous. Moreover, since $g:[0,1]\to X$ takes values in $X$, the composition $f\circ g$ takes values in $f(X)$. Thus $(f\circ g):[0,1]\to f(X)$ is a path. Now $f(g(0))=f(x)=p$ and $f(g(1))=f(y)=q$, and so $f\circ g$ is a path connecting $p$ to $q$. What part of this reasoning would you like clarified? Also, did you draw a picture and visualize the situation like I recommended?

Comment: @anon Thank you. Now I fully understood what going on!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing your terms:

- *Topological spaces* are connected and/or path connected. "Connected" is not an adjective that can be applied to a *function*
- *Functions* can be continuous or not. "Continuous" is not an adjective that can be applied to a *topological space*.

That said, what you need to prove is that $f(X)$ (which is a set) is path connected. Therefore, you need to prove, for two points $p, q$ in $f(X)$, that there exists a path in $f(X)$ from $p$ to $q$ (i.e., a *continuous* function $\gamma$ from $[0,1]$ to $f(X)$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma(1) = q$).

1. Do you understand that:

   - $f\circ g$ is continuous?
   - $f\circ g$ maps from $[0,1]$ to $f(X)$?
   - $(f\circ g)(0) = p$?
   - $(f\circ g)(1) = q$?
2. Do you understand that from these four points, it follows that $f\circ g$ is a path from $p$ to $q$?
3. Do you understand that from 2., it follows that $f(X)$ is path connected?

If you answer any of these questions with "no", please explain in the comments which part is confusing you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a great clarification!

Comment: @AlphaE Happy to help. I also advise you to check out the answer by anon, which offers a more visual explanation.

Comment: Answer by anon also is great, pictorial of same what you wrote. I accepted your answer since it was earlier!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a picture. Hope it helps.

$~~$ [image: paths]

Comment: Wow! I want a BOOK of these images!

Answer (score 0):

See definition of the path. For a space to be path-connected, for every two points you have to have a continuous something connecting two points. You can do it in $X$ by assumption. Now $f\circ g$ is continuous as a composition of two continuous functions. It also connects necessary points because $g$ does.